# How to pass an Eval method through the attributes.add property?

Tags: c#, asp.net, eval

I have a Gridview with all the rows as textboxes and one edit button in the last column. All the textboxes have an onclick property which calls a javascript method. Here is the HTML code of one of the textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtLoginName" Onclick='<%# "pass(" + Eval("userid") + ");" %>'
  Text='<%# Eval("LoginName")%>' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

When a user clicks on the **Edit** button, the onclick property is removed and the button changes to **Save**. After making the changes, when a user clicks **Save**, I want to re-add the onclick property again. This is the code I have tried:

```
protected void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button btn = (Button)sender;
            GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;
            TextBox lstTxt = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtLoginName");
            if (btn.Text == "Edit")
            {
                lstTxt.Attributes.Remove("onclick");
                btn.Text = "Save";
            }
            else
            {
                lstTxt.Attributes.Add("onclick", "<%# 'pass(" + Eval("userid") + ");' %>");
                btn.Text = "Edit";
            }
```

But its showing error

> *Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control*

How to pass that correctly?

Comment: is userid is column in gridview???

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar no its a column from the database to which the gridview is bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to get the `userid` from sonmewhere else. You could store it for example in a `HiddenField` or invisible label and use `e.Row.FindControl` to get this control. Another approach is using the button's `CommandArgument`.

aspx:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnEdit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("userid") %>'>
```

codebehind:

```
string userID = btn.CommandArgument.ToString();
lstTxt.Attributes.Add("onclick", "pass(" + userID  + ");");
```

Here is the approach with a control like `HiddenField`:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="UserID" Visible="false">
 <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:HiddenField ID="HidUserID" Value='<%#Eval("userid") %>'  runat="server" />
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Now you can get it from codebehind via `FindControl`:

```
HiddenField hidUserID = (HiddenField)e.Row.FindControl("HidUserID");
string userID = hidUserID.Value;
```

Comment: Actually there is a requirement that when a user clicks the textbox, two more gridviews are populated. For that purpose I use the hiddenfield and using its value I populate the other gridviews

Comment: Hi I have used the commandargument method and it works perfectly. Only thing is that instead of passing "<%# 'pass(" + userID  + ");' %>" I passed it "pass(" + userID + ");" in the attributes.add. Please update your answer so I can mark it.

Comment: @nitinvertigo: whoops, of course, that was a copy-paste issue. I've corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this:

use it in grid view template field

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="userid" Visible="false">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label runat="server" id="lblUserid" style="display:none" Text='<%# Eval("UserID") %>' />
</ItemTemplate>

</asp:TemplateField>
```

find in code behind

```
GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;
            Label lbl = (TextBox)row.FindControl("lblUserid");
string userid=lblUserid.Text;
lstTxt.Attributes.Add("onclick", "<%# 'pass(" + userid + ");' %>");
```

Comment: Hi I have used commandargument method suggested by Tim and it works. One thing is that you cannot pass like "<%# 'pass(" + userid + ");' %>". Instead pass it like "pass(" + userID + ");" then it works. Thanks for the answer

Comment: i used as 'userid' for 'userID' it will show error according to my code because C# is case-sensitive.

Comment: sorry my mistake. yeah you are right it should be userid for both